# How to mock the post() and get() calls of httpx in python unitest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

The following test works when I patch the entire function `get_post()` and `get_call()`. How can I patch the `httpx.post()` and `httpx.get()`?

In `src/app.py`

```
import httpx

class Client:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def post_call(self, payload):
        response = httpx.post(
                url=self.url,
                json=payload,
            )
            response.raise_for_status()
            return response.json()

    def get_call(self, id):
        response = httpx.get(
                url=self.url,
                params={"id": id},
            )

        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.json()
```

In `test/test.py`

```
from unittest.mock import patch

import httpx
import pytest
from src import app


@pytest.mark.anyio
@patch("app.get_call",return_value=httpx.Response(200, json ={"status":"passed"}))
def test_get(mocker):
    cl = Client("test-url")
    result = cl.get_call("test")
    assert result.json() == {"status":"passed"}

@pytest.mark.anyio
@patch("app.get_post", return_value=httpx.Response(200,json={"status":"passed"}),)
def test_post(mocker):
    cl = Client("test-url")
    result = cl.post_call({"data":"test"})
    assert result.json() == {"status":"passed"}
```

When I tried to patch the httpx call then I get thrown with the error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.Client'; 'app' is not a package`

Comment: Can you show us how you tried to patch those calls?

Comment: @larsks `@patch("app.httpx.get",return_value=httpx.Response(200, json ={"status":"passed"}))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Fix import paths

Assuming that your directory layout looks like this:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── app.py
└── test
    └── test_app.py
```

Then you don't want `from src import app`, because `src` isn't a package. It's just a directory. To help pytest locate `app.py`, create an empty `src/conftest.py` so that you have:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── app.py
│   └── conftest.py
└── test
    └── test_app.py
```

Then in `test_app.py`, instead of:

```
from src import app
```

Write:

```
import app
```

### Fix syntax errors

There is a missing `"` in your test code; as written, attempting to run a test will fail with:

```
E     File "/home/lars/tmp/python/test/test_app.py", line 19
E       result = cl.post_call({"data:"test"})
E                                         ^
E   SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 19)
```

We need to correct line 19 to read:

```
result = cl.post_call({"data": "test"})
```

Additionally, in your test functions you have:

```
cl = Client("test")
```

This will fail because you have `import app`, not `from app import Client`. We need to either fix the `import` statement or fix the test code:

```
cl = app.Client("test")
```

### Fix `@patch` calls

Your existing `patch` invocations are broken as written, since your `app` module has neither `get_call` or `get_post` methods -- these are methods on the Client class. Fortunately, we need to replace this by patching `httpx.get` and `httpx.post`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

import httpx
import pytest
import app


@patch("app.httpx.get")
def test_get(fake_httpx_get):
    fake_httpx_get.return_value = httpx.Response(
        200,
        json={"status": "passed"},
        request=httpx.Request("GET", "test"),
    )
    cl = app.Client("test-url")
    result = cl.get_call("test")
    assert result == {"status": "passed"}


@patch("app.httpx.post")
def test_post(fake_httpx_post):
    fake_httpx_post.return_value = httpx.Response(
        200,
        json={"status": "passed"},
        request=httpx.Request("POST", "test"),
    )
    cl = app.Client("test-url")
    result = cl.post_call({"data": "test"})
    assert result == {"status": "passed"}
```

I've moved setting the return value on the mock inside the functions because we also need to set the `request` parameter; without that your calls to `res.raise_for_status()` will fail:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot call `raise_for_status` as the request instance has not been set on this response.
```

---

With the above directory structure and test code, when we run `pytest` from the top-level directory, it results in:

```
========================================================= test session starts =========================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.1, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /home/lars/.local/share/virtualenvs/python-LD_ZK5QN/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/python
plugins: anyio-3.6.2
collected 2 items

test/test_app.py::test_get PASSED                                                                                               [ 50%]
test/test_app.py::test_post PASSED                                                                                              [100%]

========================================================== 2 passed in 0.08s ==========================================================
```

---

We can also test how your code responds to HTTP errors:

```
@patch("app.httpx.post")
def test_post_failure(fake_httpx_post):
    fake_httpx_post.return_value = httpx.Response(
        400,
        json={"status": "failed"},
        request=httpx.Request("POST", "test"),
    )
    cl = app.Client("test-url")
    with pytest.raises(httpx.HTTPStatusError):
        cl.post_call({"data": "test"})
```